# Does anyone know why this inclusion exclusion calculation isn't working?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458534/4-digit-positive-integers-that-does-not-contain-the-digits-3-and-4-plus-other-pr), the problem is to find the amount of four-digit numbers that have the following characteristics:

> All digits are unique.
>   Does not contain the digits 3 and/or 4.
>   The number is divisible by 3.

I was going to use inclusion/exclusion for this, which states:

$$N(A\cap{B})=N(A)+N(B)-N(A\cup{B})$$

Take $A$ to be the first two properties, and $B$ to be the third. It must be a $4$ digit number, and cannot contain $3$ or $4$:

$$7\cdot{7}\cdot{6}\cdot{5}$$

Now consider the number of $4$ digit numbers divisible by $3$. The amount of numbers divisible by $3$ between $1$ and $10000$ is $3333$. The amount of numbers divisible by $3$ between $1$ and $1000$ is $333$. Subtract one from the other, and the amount of numbers divisible by $3$ between $1000$ and $10000$ is $3000$.

$$N(A)=7\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\\
N(B)=3000\\
N(A\cup{B})=9000$$

This comes out to a negative number, which tells me I'm setting up my cases incorrectly. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you are counting numbers divisible by $3$, you are counting (i) those that have $3$ and/or $4$ and (ii) those with repeated digits.  I think the problem you are trying to solve may be somewhat ugly.

Comment: How did you get $N(A\cup{B})=9000$? Obviously you can't have $N(A\cup{B}) > N(A) + N(B)$, so there's something very wrong with your calculation of $N(A\cup{B})$. But in fact I can't think of a way here to calculate $N(A\cup{B})$ without also calculating $N(A\cap{B})$.

Comment: @Shreevatsa I just took $N(A\cup{B})$ to be the total amount of 4 digit numbers, but I guess that's incorrect...

Comment: @Ataraxia: $A\cup{B}$ is the set of 4-digit numbers that **either** have all digits distinct and different from 3/4, **or** are divisible by 3 (or both). For instance, a number like 1337 is not in the set $A\cup{B}$, because it neither has distinct digits, nor is it divisible by 3 (i.e. it's neither in $A$ nor in $B$, so it's not in $A\cup{B}$).

Comment: This question is asking about why their inclusion/exclusion argument didn't work, it is *not* just asking for the solution.  This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, Jim is correct. None of those in the linked question answer my question at all...

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think your comments pretty much answer the question. Do you mind if I turn them into an answer?

Comment: @askyle: Sure, feel free.

Comment: There is nothing in the statement of the question here that says we're dealing with a 4-digit number. If that's part of the question, please edit it in.

Comment: @Ataraxia Is your question answered now? It'd be nice to get this one out of the queue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458556/does-anyone-know-why-this-inclusion-exclusion-calculation-isnt-working?noredirect=1#comment987068_458556) [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458556/does-anyone-know-why-this-inclusion-exclusion-calculation-isnt-working?noredirect=1#comment987078_458556) by @ShreevatsaR pretty much nail it. I'll "answerify":

It's not working because $N(A\cup B)\neq 9000$. The OP [assumed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458556/does-anyone-know-why-this-inclusion-exclusion-calculation-isnt-working?noredirect=1#comment987072_458556) that $A\cup B$ covers all the numbers between $1000$ and $9999$ (inclusive). However, [1337](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458556/does-anyone-know-why-this-inclusion-exclusion-calculation-isnt-working?noredirect=1#comment987078_458556) is neither in $A$ nor $B$, so it's not in the union.

The question then becomes, how do we count $N(A\cup B)$? I for one don't see a better answer than… [count $N(A\cap B)$ directly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458542/138178) and use inclusion-exclusion as:

$$ N(A\cup B) = N(A) + N(B) - N(A\cap B) $$

which AFAIK is the more common statement of the principle.

In general, given two properties it is often more straightforward to count how many elements have *both* properties at the same time than how many elements have *at least one* of the properties, precisely because one has to consider the cases in which they overlap. Sometimes one can count the union "directly" with De Morgan's law $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$, which again reduces the problem to counting an intersection instead of a union.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether inclusion/exclusion is the simplest way to deal with this problem. I'd rather enumerate the cases directly.

The set of available digits can be partitioned according to the remainder modulo $3$ as follows:
$$A=\{0,6,9\}, \quad B=\{1,7\},\quad C=\{2,5,8\}\ .$$
Denoting the number of digits chosen from $A$ by $x_A$, and similarly for the other two, we have
$$x_A+x_B+x_C=4, \qquad x_B=x_C\ ({\rm mod}\ 3)\ .$$
As $x_A\leq 3$ and $x_B\leq2$ this leaves the possibilities 
$$\eqalign{{\rm (i)}\quad &x_A=2, \quad x_B=x_C=1,\cr 
{\rm (ii)}\quad &x_A=1, \quad  x_B=0,\quad x_C=3,\cr
{\rm (iii)} \quad &x_A=0, \quad x_B=x_C=2\ .\cr}$$
In case (i) the digits can be chosen in ${3\choose 2}\cdot 2\cdot 3=18$ ways, and one can then arrange them in $18\cdot4!=432$ ways. $12$ of the $18$ choices of the digits contain $0$, so that $12\cdot 3!=72$ of these $432$ arrangements begin with $0$, which is not admissible. This leaves $432-72=360$ admissible arrangements of type (i).

In case (ii) the digits can be chosen in $3\cdot 1=3$ and arranged in $3\cdot 4!=72$ ways. $6$ of these arrangements begin with $0$ and are not admissible, so that we obtain $66$ arrangements of type (ii).

In case (iii) the digits can be chosen in $1\cdot{3\choose 2}=3$ and then be arranged in $3\cdot 4!=72$ ways.

Therefore we obtain a total of $360+66+72=498$ admissible four digit numbers.